# How to move cursor to next wrapped line in Vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

For example, if I have a long line wrapped several times, it is painful to move cursor inside this line, I have to hit <kbd>w</kbd> repeatedly, or use <kbd>f</kbd> to find what I want, even slower if there are many same letters in that line.

Can I configure Vim to make <kbd>j</kbd> to go down to next line on screen instead of the "real" next line? Or there are better approaches?

In addition, I know the `wrap` option can make a line on scree is a real line, but I want to display the whole line on screen, save my time of scrolling.

I'm using Gvim 7.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using 'gj' and 'gk' instead of just 'j' and 'k' allows moving down and up by screen lines instead of file lines. Here are a few nifty mappings for that:

- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_by_screen_lines_instead_of_file_lines